# Why is there a reserved spot in the Launcher?

Tags: 12.04, launcher

Why is there a spot reserved for a Launcher icon?  See the arrow in the image, please.  Is this a missing icon?  Hovering reveals nothing.  Hover-right-click provides an unlock-from-launcher option.

[image: Launcher Image]

Edit: I was requested to click it.  Nothing happens upon a click. Well at least I don't have much evidence that anything happened when I clicked it. I hope it doesn't launch nuclear missiles.

Comment: and clicking it starts a program? >:)

Comment: If clicking this starts a program, please edit your question to provide more information, including what program starts (or any information you can see about what is going on). If clicking this spot does nothing, you've probably found a bug in unity; in that case, I recommend [reporting this as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs/).

Comment: Clicking it does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

log out or restart your computer. I've had this happen before, you've probably got an additional program drug into your launch menu but Unity hasn't caught up to displaying it. After restarting the icon of whatever program you've placed there should become visible (or the space will disappear.)

EDIT: Also, there are some programs which do not play nice with Unity and create extra icons in it's launch bar. They're usually programs you already have in it but they don't know how to tell that they're already in it so they make more icons for themselves.

Comment: Reboots do not cause the icon to appear and the blank space remains.  I unlocked the blank icon from the launcher since I probably don't need to invoke something that does nothing.

Comment: If it happens again I'd probably start looking at the program you ran right before it happened. This is usually the culprit.